# slide effect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-effects

I'd like to create a slide effect using jQuery. I have several div's:

```
<div id='div_1'>content currently displayed</div>
<div id='div_2' style="display:none">content to be loaded</div>
<div id='div_3' style="display:none">content to be loaded</div>
```

The idea is that div_2 appears while sliding and "pushing" div_1 out of sight, a little like scrolling a window (horizontal or vertical). I think I can't use actual scrolling because the divs' content is loading via ajax, so I can't position it precisely before it's loaded.

Any idea?

TIA

greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg, it sounds like you are looking for something like I have done here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2E5Qv/

If so, what you want to do is to contain all of those `<div>`s inside a parent, and then when you want to slide them, animate the top of each div up the correct number of pixels.  The solution I provided above has each `<div>` more or less set to a fixed height of 20px (via `line-height`).

The parent `<div>` acts as a sort of window to show only the current content.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely the effect I'm looking for. I tried it this way (scrolling) but was not successful because of the ajax loading of the content. I'll try again and put some more elaborate code sample.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this:

```
$('#div_2').slideDown('slow', function(){
  $('#div_1').slideUp('slow');
});
```

[See the working demo here.](http://jsbin.com/emowu3)

Comment: wow that was fast! it's quite like this, but I want div_1 to be "pushed", ie slide too...

Comment: @greg: The first div won't slide because it is shown already.

Answer (score 0):

I took what Sarfraz provided and modified it slightly based on what I think you were looking for. For the sake of the demo, I also made it fire on the click event. You can find the working example here: http://jsbin.com/emowu3/3

```
$('#div_1').click(function(){
    $('#div_1').slideUp('slow');
    $('#div_2').slideDown('slow');
});
$('#div_2').click(function(){
    $('#div_2').slideUp('slow');
    $('#div_3').slideDown('slow');
});
$('#div_3').click(function(){
    $('#div_3').slideUp('slow');
    $('#div_1').slideDown('slow');
});
```